# Getting Unknown error. admin-restricted-operation. Signing In using Firebase anonymous Sign in in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have enabled the anonymous sign in method in firebase project. and this is the code I am trying to make an anonymous login:

```
try {
  final userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  print("Signed in with temporary account.");
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  switch (e.code) {
    case "operation-not-allowed":
      print("Anonymous auth hasn't been enabled for this project.");
      break;
    default:
      print("Unknown error. ${e.code}");
  }
}
```

I do have added this code in my main function:

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'test',
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  ).catchError((e) {
    print('FB ERROR: $e');
  });
```

But still I am getting an error when I do try to sign in it gives an error:

```
Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter (32729): Unknown error. admin-restricted-operation.
```

I have tried to search out a lot but couldn't any thing related

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code in main.dart page like this?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

if your problem is not solved if initializeApp() contains in multiple places can you remove them?
For help: This is how I use this method in my projects.

This code is my anonymous sign-in method (auth_service.dart):

```
final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<User?> signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      final UserCredential userCredentials =
      await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
      return userCredentials.user;
    } catch (_) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Code of my login page (login_view.dart):

```
bool _isLoading = false;

Future<void> _signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      Provider.of<AuthService>(context,listen: false).signInAnonymously();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      _showErrorDialog(e.code);
    } catch (e) {
      _showErrorDialog(e.toString());
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Since I'm using the provider package here, `Provider.of<AuthService>(context,listen: false).signInAnonymously();` I wrote it this way. You can also use it directly as `signInAnonymously();`.

```
MyRaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("Anonymous",),
                  onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _signInAnonymously,
                ),
```

I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.

Comment: no it has not helped i have changed the according to the one you have mentioned and have used your code to sign in but still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm that you have enabled AnonymousSignIn
2. Replace your Google-services.json file and check again.